# Lower central series starts with index 0, but upper central series starts with index 1, why?

Tags: group-theory

In every source I have seen the lower central series starts with index 0:

$ 1 = Z_0 \leq Z(G) = Z_1 \leq Z_2 \leq \cdots $

and the upper central series starts with index 1:

$ G = G_1 \geq [G,G] = G' = G_2 \geq [G_2,G] = G_3 \geq G_4 \geq \cdots $

Is there any reason for that?
Wouldn't it be nicer if the lower central series would start with index 0 as well?

Answer (score 3):

*If* we follow the notation for lower central series in the way you considered, then one of the interesting property of it is 
$$[G_i,G_j]\leq G_{i+j}.$$

Changing the index in L.C.S. will change *at least* this property.

There are some other reasons, see for example, *Structure of Groups of Prime Power Order*, C. R. Leedham-Green and McKay. (see this link [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=34khoLiyP_QC&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=the%20next%20result%20is%20immediate%20consequence%20of%20...%20Green&source=bl&ots=4nB7P2nAGV&sig=MSURn52p2PCybMmjxYnBrrUuysU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQuYvKhqbLAhUUVI4KHUVmAMUQ6AEINTAF#v=onepage&q=the%20next%20result%20is%20immediate%20consequence%20of%20...%20Green&f=false)), with comments after Lemma 1.1.19 and 1.1.24 in the book.